How to cut/crop an image file in the half in console
I have an image file image.png, and I want to make a vertical cut in the half and generate two images of equal size.

With imagemagick:
magick image.png -crop 50%x100% output_%d.png

Documentation

With ffmpeg:
ffmpeg -i image.png -vf "crop=iw/2:ih:0:0" output_1.png
ffmpeg -i image.png -vf "crop=iw/2:ih:iw/2:0" output_2.png

Documentation
